# Shinyglide jumping back to previous screen when next_condition is set

Tags: r, shiny, glidejs

I have a `shiny` app in which a `datatable` is displayed and upon a click on a row, a `modalDialog` opens in which I embedded a `glide` from `shinyglide`. This worked fine until I introduced a `next_condition` to the second screen. Now whenever the first box is selected (or after deselecting everything and selecting again), the `glide` jumps back to the first screen. If you now change the option on the first screen, then the behaviour gets very strange altogether. I have no idea what causes this or where to start to fix it. Below is a (not so small) mockup example of my app which includes the observed behaviour (if you uncomment the `next_condition`, everything works fine). The important part to the problem is the `server` part in the end, the rest is just setup to make the app fully functional.

#### **UPDATE:**

I have tried to shorten the example by getting rid of the `datatable` and the `modalDialog`, but I could not replicate the behaviour this way. So it seems to me the interaction between `modalDialog` and `glide` is at fault. I was however able to shorten it a tiny bit by getting rid of the reactive variables without changing the result.

#### **UPDATE 2:**

Also posted it [here](https://github.com/juba/shinyglide/issues/37), but the answer has not (yet) worked for me.

#### **Code:**

Library Calls:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyglide)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
```

UI:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = 'purple',
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Shinyglide Example"),
                    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
                    dashboardBody(
                        useShinyjs(),
                        tags$head(tags$style("#modal1 .modal-body {min-height:750px; padding: 10px}
                       #modal1 .modal-dialog { width: 1280px; height: 1280px;}"
                        )),
                        
                        fixedRow(
                            column(width = 12,
                                   box(title = "I am the table!",width = NULL,status = 'info',solidHeader = TRUE,
                                       DT::dataTableOutput("table")))
                        )
                    )
)
```

Setup Functions:

```
render_my_table <- function(){
    col_a <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
    col_b <- c("Human","Cat","Human","Dog","Dog")
    col_c <- c(35,7,42,5,11)
    col_d <- c("Earth","Earth","Earth","Earth","Mars")
    
    my_data <- data.frame(letter = col_a,species = col_b,age = col_c,planet = col_d)
    my_data <- datatable(my_data,colnames = c("ID","Species","Age","Home Planet"),rownames = FALSE,filter = 'top',selection = 'single',
                         callback = JS("table.on('click.dt','tr',function() {
                                        Shiny.onInputChange('rows',table.rows(this).data().toArray(),{priority:'event'});});"))
    return(my_data)
}

pickerinput_choices <- function(my_species){
    if(my_species == "Human"){
        return(c("Job","Family","Mortgage"))
    }else{
        return(c("Breed","Owner","Family"))
    }
}

advanced_inputs <- function(my_species,my_choiceA){
    
    if(is.null(my_choiceA)){return(0)}
    
    if(my_choiceA == "Job"){
        return(checkboxGroupInput("my_checkbox",label = "Type of Jobs",choices = c("Employed","Self-Employed","Apprenticeship")))
    }else if(my_choiceA == "Mortgage"){
        return(checkboxGroupInput("my_checkbox",label = "Type of Housing",choices = c("Apartment","House")))
    }else if(my_choiceA == "Breed"){
        return(checkboxGroupInput("my_checkbox",label = "Details",choices = c("Height","Fur","Weight")))
    }else if(my_choiceA == "Owner"){
        return(checkboxGroupInput("my_checkbox",label = "Details",choices = c("Age","Employed","Children")))
    }else{
        if(my_species == "Human"){
            return(checkboxGroupInput("my_checkbox",label = "Details",choices = c("Partner","Parents","Children","Siblings")))
        }else{
            return(checkboxGroupInput("my_checkbox",label = "Details",choices = c("Owner","Children","Owners of Children")))
        }
    }
}
```

**Server:**

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    glide_modal <- modalDialog(
        renderUI({title = tags$span(paste("You have chosen Row",input$rows[1]),style = "font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold")}),
        footer = NULL,
        easyClose = TRUE,
        glide(
            id = "my_glide",
            controls_position = 'bottom',
            height = "800px",
            screen(
                renderUI({
                    pickerInput(inputId = "my_pickerinput",h3("Make Choice A"),choices = pickerinput_choices(input$rows[2]),
                                options = pickerOptions(container = 'body'))
                })
            ),
            screen(
                renderUI({
                    tagList(
                        h3("Make Choice B"),
                        advanced_inputs(input$rows[2],input$my_pickerinput)
                    )
                }),
                next_condition = "(typeof input['my_checkbox'] !== 'undefined' && input['my_checkbox'].length > 0)"
            ),
            screen(
                renderText({
                    paste("You have selected row",input$rows[1],"which is a",input$rows[2],"and have requested information about",
                          input$my_pickerinput,", especially about",paste(input$my_checkbox,collapse = " and "))
                })
            )
        )
    )
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        render_my_table()
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$rows,{
        showModal(tags$div(id="modal1",glide_modal))
    })
}
```

and function call:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can shorten your example. It will be easier for other people to help you once you get rid of all code that is unrelated to your actual issue

Comment: I'll see if I can shorten it, but I think two things here are important:

1) The input in the next_condition is stored reactively and
2) the options change depending on what is selected on the first screen and are also stored reactively.

Also I need to set up the entire datatable -> modal -> glide chain to reproduce the setting truthfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by the newest development version thanks to the package author. See the github thread, the code works now as posted in the question.